# Version upgrade magento 2 to magento 2.0.2 error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I got an error while upgrade from magento2 tp 2.0.2

System Upgrade Status:
Update application is not running

Kindly let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Magento requires a total of three cron jobs, one of which is for the updater. Please review [this topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron) and let us know if it helps.